# Как открыть настройки уведомлений на телефоне при нажатии на кнопкуUI Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось окно настроек уведомлений на телефоне.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы сделать что-то за пределами приложения в Android, нужно использовать [Deep Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/deep-linking-android.html), например [Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS), где все настройки приложения включая `Permission` (разрешения) и на уведомления в частности. Тот ещё геморой и это только на Adroid, а у iOS своя история и к чему этот экстрим?

---

Как можно заметить, никто не открывает окно настроек, все в основном запрашивают у операционки permission и она сама открывает соответствующее диалоговое окно с вопросом пользователю, как правило при старте приложения и через скрипт в случаях по необходимости, когда пользователь хочет включить/воспользоваться некой функцию.

Для этого нужно скачать через `Package Manager` соответствующий пакет для работы с уведомлениями `Mobile Notifications`. В [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.3/manual/Settings.html) указано, как можно запросить разрешение при старте приложения или через скрипт. Для Android и iOS разная реализация, но всё сводится к авторизации с отправкой и ничем больше заниматься не нужно. Легко и удобно можно послать `ваша ферма построена`.